# OneLogin SSO java implementation

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, onelogin

first of all I don't know much about SSO login but I have to integrate it for java application  i'm working on. For what I understood OneLogin has developed a saml implemented that is easier to add to our applications. The thing here is I don't understand if I can use this toolkit with a Identity provider provided by my company. It seems that oneLogin sso implementation can only be use with OneLogin identity provider.

Can someone enlighten me about this ?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of java-saml.

OneLogin Java SAML Toolkit can be used with any SAML Identity Provider.